# SetupAPI in IoTCore?

Tags: windows-10-iot-core, windows-iot-core-10, setupapi

### Can I use SetupApi Functions in windows10 IoTCore?

**I writed only one line :**

`HDEVINFO Handle = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL,NULL,NULL,DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);`

**But** 
**Handle = 0xfff...**
**GetlastError = 127 means "The specified procedure could not be found."**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue and your code works for me. I test on Raspberry Pi 3 with Windows 10 IoT Core version 17763.1.

The code I used in a Windows IoT Core Console Application and debug follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/remotedebugging):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    HDEVINFO Handle = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
    DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
}
```

You can have a try to see if it works.

I upload my project [here](https://github.com/luyaok/Windows-IoT-tests).